# Zend modification. Adding MySQL FORCE INDEX hint

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-select

I am trying to extend the Zend library in order to get queries like this one:

```
SELECT * FROM item i **force index(ix)** ORDER BY date LIMIT 100;
```

I am working arround with this Zend forum issue solution: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7570

However I have a problem. Look at the code below.

```
$select->forceIndex('index');
echo $select->assemble();
     //  I get the right SELECT query with the force index hint
$this->fecthAll($select);
    //  The server execute a wrong SELECT query without the force index hint
```

Some help?

Comment: just guessing .. `$this->fetchAll($select->assemble())` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not pretty sure why, but if I remove the echo clause, fetchAll executes the right query...

So that's the answer, **remove echo**

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the patch you are using is broken. If you check the source, it unsets the FORCE INDEX parts when creating the query the first time.

If you check it, $select->assemble() == $select->assemble() should give false.